# Lebesgue density of the random vector $(X,X+Y)$ where $X$ and $Y$ are exponentially distributed to different parameters

Tags: probability-theory, probability-distributions, exponential-distribution

I want to find the density of the random vector $(X,X+Y)$ where $X\sim\text{Exp}_\alpha$ and $Y\sim\text{Exp}_\beta$ are exponentially distributed to different rate parameters $\alpha\ne \beta$.

I don't think I can use the product-density, as $X, X+Y$ are certainly not independent, but this is the only way I've ever seen a joint density done.

How can I proceed to calculate this density? Is there a rule I can use?

EDIT: More precisely, how can I get from $P(X\le a, X+Y\le b)$ to a place where I can actually use the known probability densities of $X,Y$? I can't split the probability because of dependence issues.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to assume independence between $X$ and $Y$ then you can  use the fundamental transformation theorem (Jacobian).
For our knowledge, you have also to tell us if $\alpha$ and $\beta$ are "scale" or "rate" parameter because this modifies the density expression

---

Let's set

$$\begin{cases}
v=x+y\\
u=x
\end{cases}\rightarrow \begin{cases}
x=u\\
y=v-u
\end{cases}$$

The Jacobian is evidently $|J|=1$ thus

$$f_{UV}(u,v)=\alpha e^{-\alpha u}\beta e^{-\beta(v-u)}=\alpha \beta e^{-(\alpha-\beta)u}e^{-\beta v}$$

The only difficulty now is to understand which is the $(U,V)$ support. It is quite easy to understand that it must be $0<u<v<\infty$ thus the requested joint density is

$$f_{UV}(u,v)=\alpha \beta e^{-(\alpha-\beta)u}e^{-\beta v}\cdot\mathbb{1}_{[0;\infty)}(u)\cdot\mathbb{1}_{[u;\infty)}(v)$$

---

**Useful observation**

---

Now let's set $\alpha=\beta$ thus we have

$$f_{UV}(u,v)=\alpha^2 e^{-\alpha v}\cdot\mathbb{1}_{[0;\infty)}(u)\cdot\mathbb{1}_{[u;\infty)}(v)$$

Which integrated in $du$ gives us

$$f_V(v)=\int_{0}^v \alpha^2 e^{-\alpha v}du=\alpha^2 v e^{-\alpha v}\sim Gamma(2;\alpha)$$

as already known by Gamma distribution properties.

Comment: Its the rate parameter, I've edited. I couldn't find anything for "fundamental transformation theorem", what do you mean exactly?

Comment: @RubenKruepper:  see my edits